# ¿Cómo guardar una relación belongsToMany?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Tengo una relación belongsToMany entre Pieza y herramienta con una tabla pivot.

Una pieza se fabrica con una o mas herramientas.
Lo que pretendo lograr en este momento es asociar, relacionar todas esas herramientas que ingreso dinámicamente en mi formulario con su pieza correspondiente.

Esta es mi tabla dinámica:

```
<div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Detalles de herramientas</h3>                
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">  

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" id="dynamicTable">  
                <tr>
                    <th>Posición</th>
                    <th>Herramienta</th>                 
                    <th>Inserto</th>                 
                    <th>Calidad</th>                 
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>  
                    <td><input type="text" name="position[]" placeholder="Posicion" class="form-control select2" /></td>  
                    <td><input type="text" name="code_tool[]" placeholder="Codigo" class="form-control" /></td> 
                    <td><input type="text" name="code_insert[]" placeholder="Codigo" class="form-control" /></td> 
                    <td><input type="text" name="quality[]" placeholder="Calidad" class="form-control" /></td>                      
                    <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></button></td>  
                </tr>  
            </table> 

            </div>
        </div>
```

En el método store básicamente realizo lo siguiente:

capturo los datos ingresado dinámicamente de mi formulario que  provienen en formato de array, estos son inserto y herramienta, una herramienta puede tener de uno a mas insertos, entonces capturo los datos ingresados, asocio el inserto a su herramienta, luego pretendo  asociar esas herramientas ingresadas a su pieza correspondiente,  pero no lo he logrado aun

lo he intentado con esto sin efecto:

```
 $piece->tools()->sync($request->$tools);
```

Este es mi controlador: metodo store

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        if ($request->ajax()){
            try {
                //  Transacciones
                DB::beginTransaction();              


                // dd($request->all());
                // campos dinamicos 
                $position    = $request->position;
                $code_tool   = $request->code_tool;
                $code_insert = $request->code_insert;
                $quality     = $request->quality;                 

                //recorro el array, creo el inserto luego lo asocio a su herramienta correspondiente
                for($count = 0; $count < count($position); $count++)
                {
                    $insert = array(                        
                        'code_insert' => $code_insert[$count],
                        'quality'     => $quality[$count]

                    );

                    $insert = new Insert();
                    $insert->code_insert =  $code_insert[$count];
                    $insert->quality = $quality[$count];

                    if($insert->save()){
                        $tool = array(
                        'position'    => $position[$count],
                        'code_tool'   => $code_tool[$count],
                        'insert_id'   => $insert->id
                        );
                        $tool_data[] = $tool;
                    }                 
                }
                // dd($tool_data);             

                $tools = Tool::insert($tool_data);

                $gag     = Gag::create($request->all());
                $program = Program::create($request->all()); 

                $piece = $program->piece()->create([
                    'denomination' => $request['denomination'],
                    'code'         => $request['code'],
                    'time'         => $request['time'],
                    'part_piece'   => $request['part_piece'],
                    'gag_id'       => $gag->id
                ]);
                dd($piece);

                //en  este punto debería de asociar a todas las herramientas ingresadas a su pieza correspondiente
                $piece->tools()->sync($request->$tools);

                DB::commit();

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // anula la transacion
                DB::rollBack();
            }
        }    
    }
```

justamente haciendo esto antes de asociarla

```
dd($piece);
$piece->tools()->sync($request->$tools);
```

obtengo lo siguiente:

```
Piece {#1062
  #fillable: array:7 [
    0 => "program_id"
    1 => "gag_id"
    2 => "denomination"
    3 => "code"
    4 => "part_piece"
    5 => "time"
    6 => "observation"
  ]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "pieces"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: true
  #attributes: array:9 [
    "denomination" => "prueba6"
    "code" => "prueba6"
    "time" => "01:46:18"
    "part_piece" => "1"
    "gag_id" => 9
    "program_id" => 8
    "updated_at" => "2020-01-29 21:53:14"
    "created_at" => "2020-01-29 21:53:14"
    "id" => 8
  ]
  #original: array:9 [
    "denomination" => "prueba6"
    "code" => "prueba6"
    "time" => "01:46:18"
    "part_piece" => "1"
    "gag_id" => 9
    "program_id" => 8
    "updated_at" => "2020-01-29 21:53:14"
    "created_at" => "2020-01-29 21:53:14"
    "id" => 8
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

**¿Como deberia de asociar las herramientas empleadas en la fabricaion de la pieza?**

modelo Piece:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Piece extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'program_id', 'gag_id', 'denomination', 'code', 'part_piece', 'time', 'observation'
    ];    

    public function program()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo(Program::class);
    }  

    public function gag()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Gag::class);
    } 

    public function tools() 
    {        
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tool::class)->withTimestamps();
    }   

}
```

modelo Tool:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tool extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'insert_id', 'position', 'code_tool', 'type', 'category', 'status', 'description', 'reason'
    ];   

    public function inserts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Insert::class);
    }    

    public function pieces()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Piece::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Comment: Una pieza puede tener varias herramientas, ¿y una herramienta puede estar en varias piezas o solo en una?

Comment: @Shaz Una pieza puede tener de una a varias herramientas, y una  misma herramienta puede estar en una a varias piezas.

Comment: ¿Qué contiene `$request->tools`? Muestra un dump() de dicha información.

Comment: @Shaz si te refieres a esto ``` dd($request->$tools);``` justamente despues de insertar una nueva pieza me arrojo esto: null,

Comment: Una cosa es dd() y otra es dump(), aunque el resultado es similar, por favor lee la documentación de Laravel. Si dicha variable está vacía, quiere decir que no la está recibiendo del formulario. ¿De dónde sale `$request->tools`?

Comment: esta bien todabia no domino laravel, pero lo analizado asi, si con esto:   ```$tools = Tool::insert($tool_data);``` creo una herramienta y la asocio a un inserto, lo digo porque asi lo veo en mis tablas se inserta una herramienta y se relaciona con su inserto, entoces con esto deberia de asociar las herramientas a su pieza ```$piece->tools()->sync($request->$tools); ```

Comment: Uff, creo que estás bastante confundido sobre cómo funciona Laravel, y realmente es muy largo de explicar los múltiples errores que tienes, por favor revisa la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#inserts . En cuanto a `$request->tools`, estás trabajando con información inexistente, puesto que el Request no trae dicha información (al menos no directamente) del formulario.

Comment: ok revisare la documentación, pero sinceramente estoy tardando demasiado tiempo en esto, si has entendido mi problema porque no me ayudas a corregir mis errores, indicando como podria mejorar tal o cual cosa, yo simplemente tengo una tabla dinamica donde ingreso las herramientas junto a sus insertos, luego de crearlas debo asociar esas herramientas a su pieza